# How to start Mosquitto broker service on Windows 7 from command prompt?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, microsoft-windows

I have set up [Mosquitto MQTT](https://mosquitto.org/) on my Windows 7 laptop. I have performed the installation process according to this step by step [guide](https://sivatechworld.wordpress.com/2015/06/11/step-by-step-installing-and-configuring-mosquitto-with-windows-7/).

Installation was alright and I could start the Mosquitto Broker's service by using `C:\Windows\system32\services`.

[image: windows service overview showing mosquitto broker service]

---

Now what I want is to be able to launch the service from Windows 7 command prompt. In everycase I tried to run the commands from the install directory of Mosquitto (`D:\..\MQTT\mosquitto>`).

1. First I have tried the following command according to the [documentation](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-8.html):

   ```
   mosquitto -d
   ```

   > -d, --daemon
   >
   > Run mosquitto in the background as a daemon. All other behaviour remains the same.

   Turned out that I cannot do this on Windows.

   ```
   1483193297: Warning: Can't start in daemon mode in Windows.
   ```
2. After, I have tried a command shared on this [site](http://www.embedded101.com/Develop-M2M-IoT-Devices-Ebook/DevelopM2MIoTDevicesContent/articleid/237?dnnprintmode=true&mid=948&SkinSrc=%5BG%5DSkins%2F_default%2FNo%20Skin&ContainerSrc=%5BG%5DContainers%2F_default%2FNo%20Container).

   ```
   mosquitto –p 1883 –v
   ```

   This one started the broker but not the background service. I have checked the service among the Windows services, and Mosquitto Broker was not started.

---

Does anyone know the proper way of starting Mosquitto broker's service from Windows 7 command prompt?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally succeeded in finding the correct command on this [site](https://www.kepware.com/support/knowledge-base/default.asp?solution=/_ui/selfservice/pkb/PublicKnowledgeSolution/d?&id=50133000000f9YF). It is:

```
net start mosquitto
```

It can be run from any directory. If you receive the following error:

```
D:\..\MQTT\mosquitto>net start mosquitto
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

then you need to run the command prompt as an administrator. In case of success the following response will be shown.

```
D:\..\MQTT\mosquitto>net start mosquitto
The Mosquitto Broker service is starting.
The Mosquitto Broker service was started successfully.
```